# Using anyOf to see objects name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

I have a schema here where I would like to have a drop down, to select an option, and from there - depending on the selection different options appear; all being nested within an array to have multiples of them.

I have noticed that when I am filling in with dummy data, the output json isnt storing the name of the selected option

so the data.json looks something like this:

```
{
  "page1": [
    {
      "imageOptions": {
        "imageHeightType": "vh",
        "imageHeight": 50
      },
      "textboxArea": {
        "headerText": "Header for selection1",
        "headingTag": "h1",
        "textBoxOpacity": 15
      }
    },
    {
      "content": "This is a complety different selection, yet there is no name to tell the difference between these two difference objects"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see theres no object to wrap these two different items within the page1 array - Ideally would like something like:

```
{
  "page1": [
    {
     // Title of object goes here from schema
      "imageOptions": {
        "imageHeightType": "vh",
        "imageHeight": 50
      },
      "textboxArea": {
        "headerText": "Header for selection1",
        "headingTag": "h1",
        "textBoxOpacity": 15
      }
    },
    {
      // Title of object goes here from schema
      "content": "This is a completely different selection, yet there is no name to tell the difference between these two difference objects"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to make this so? I have looked on the docs for AnyOf but not much luck. Quite new to React-JsonSchema-Forms.

Below is my current Schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "page1": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "title": "Full Width Image",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "imageOptions": {
                "type": "object",
                "title": "Image",
                "properties": {
                  "image": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "Image",
                    "format": "data-url"
                  },
                  "imageHeightType": {
                    "enum": [
                      "px",
                      "vh"
                    ]
                  },
                  "imageHeight": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "title": "Image Height"
                  }
                }
              },
              "textboxArea": {
                "type": "object",
                "title": "Textbox Area",
                "properties": {
                  "headerText": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "Heading Text"
                  },
                  "headingTag": {
                    "enum": [
                      "h1",
                      "h2",
                      "h3"
                    ]
                  },
                  "imageText": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "Body Text"
                  },
                  "textboxPosition": {
                    "title": "Textbox Position",
                    "enum": [
                      "Left",
                      "Center",
                      "Right"
                    ]
                  },
                  "textboxColor": {
                    "title": "Color of Textbox Area",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "textBoxOpacity": {
                    "title": "Textbox Opacity %",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "minimum": 0,
                    "maximum": 100,
                    "multipleOf": 5
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "title": "Custom Block",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "content": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also [Link](https://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/#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) to the online schema editor if it helps understand my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add a name-like property to each object? You can then hide/disable it if you want:

schema:

```
"anyOf": [
    {
        "title": "Full Width Image",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "default": "fullWidthImage"
            },
            "imageOptions": {
                "type": "object",
                "title": "Image",
                "properties": {...}
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "Custom Block",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "default": "custom"
            },
            "content": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

uiSchema:

```
{
    "page1": {
    "items": {
        "name": {
            "ui:widget": "hidden"
        },
        "imageOptions": {...},
        ...
    }
}
```

formData then should look like this:

```
{
    "page1": [
        {
            "name": "fullWidthImage",
            "imageOptions": {
                "imageHeightType": "vh",
                "imageHeight": 50
            },
            "textboxArea": {
                "headerText": "Header for selection1",
                "headingTag": "h1",
                "textBoxOpacity": 15
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "custom",
            "content": "This is a complety different selection, yet there is no name to tell the difference between these two difference objects"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does the default work though? when using it in the playground it doesnt actually update the data json. or is this a bug within the playground and works fine when used?

Comment: Oh... I just saw this: https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/issues/975
The "default" does work (you can see the simple example in the playground) but I guess it's a bug with how anyOf/oneOf are handled... =(

Comment: This is now working as of V1.7.0 - https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/releases/tag/v1.7.0